# Deploy C# DLL library with dependecies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, dependencies

I have an application (let's call it A) which loads the DLL plugins from the folder Plugins. I have created a plugin dll (let's call it B). My plugin dll is written in C# and have some dependencies like CEFSHARP DLL. The only way the Application A can load my Plugin dll B if I will copy all the CefSharp DLL needed dependencies to Application A folder. My question would be:

How to make an install setup file so it would install necessary dependencies to some kind of folder and Application A would know where those are? Plugin B don't have to be transferred to Plugins folder during the install. Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do a lot with WIX

Answer (score 1):

If the application is implemented well, it should come with an `app.config` (that's the name in Visual Studio) or `myapp.exe.config` (that's the name after it was compiled) file that searches for dependent DLLs in the plugin folder, like

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="plugins" />
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Your plugin would then have all its dependencies side-by-side and there's no need to put them into the application's installation directory.

With [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) you could do it as follows:

- let the user select the application A installation directory (ideally: use a Pascal script to detect it automatically, e.g. from Registry and do not let the user choose it)
- install the dependencies into the selected directory
- install the plugin into the `plugins` subdirectory

Here are the relevant lines of an InnoSetup script:

```
[Setup]
DefaultDirName={pf}\App A
[Files]
Source: "./myplugin.dll"; DestDir: "{app}/plugins"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "./dependency.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
```

Comment: I didn't compile or built Application A it is 3rd party application that provides a DLL file with a base class which can be extended in my Plugin B. The problem I am facing that if I will put all dependencies into Plugins folder it does not work, it shows missing dependencies error.

Comment: Then contact the vendor and tell him that his plugin concept does not work.

Comment: I will check this as a topic answer :)) Are there any other hacks to bypass it without contacting the vendor? If there are not then I will just contact the vendor and file a bug. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to do what I need using InnoSetup? Thanks.